# knockout validation regex not evaluating properly

Tags: regex, validation, knockout.js

I am using knockoutjs and knockout validation. I am attempting to restrict semicolons from being entered. I have tried this:

```
.extend({ pattern: { params: "[^;]"} });
```

..somehow when I enter 'pppppp' into my text input it is considered invalid. but 'eee' is valid, please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually, the whole input is validated unless this just validates a keystroke, ie: is the key just enterred Not a semi-colon. Otherwise, it could be `[^;]+` if it implies beginning to end, `^[^;]+$` if it doesn't.

Comment: This does not appear to have any effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that you need to include a custom message, or not use a wrapping object.

[Check out this js fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/PV6Rm/1/)

The following constructions are valid:

```
.extend({
    pattern: {
        params: '^[^;]*$'
        , message:"fail"
    }
})
```

or

```
extend({
    pattern: '^[^;]*$'
})
```

However, this results in unexpected behaviour:

```
.extend({
    pattern: {
        params: '^[^;]*$'
    }
})
```

Comment: Oddly enough this solved the problem. I am still not entirely sure why but it works - thanks!

Comment: Likely, somewhere the code naively calls `field.pattern.message` and tries to treat it like a string.  This generates an error which causes the validation to fail.